# cocoaPods error :duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods

Tags: cocoapods

I make a xx.a（use cocoaPods） serve it to others,they want to use it in a project which used cocoaPods too,get this error:

duplicate symbol OBJC_METACLASS$PodsDummy_Pods in:
xx.a(Pods-dummy.o)
other.a(Pods-dummy.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS$_PodsDummy_Pods in:
xx.a(Pods-dummy.o)
other.a(Pods-dummy.o)

How can I resolve it? Can I delete the Pods-dummy.o from xx.a?

Comment: just delete it solve my problem

Comment: How did you delete it?

Comment: @jeremykrall i use a tool  you can try it ,https://github.com/Leon1108/slt

Answer (score 1):

Having duplicate symbol.

You can safely delete them from the Archive.

Comment: How do you delete them from the archive? I'm having the exact same issue.